# Check and Retrieve those results where a cell(row) contains atleast one value from many values in a column

Tags: mysql

Let me give you an example :

---

I have a **table (name = posts)** which contains following rows:

```
   id    |    title   | .... |  names
    1    |      .     |   .  |
    .    |      .     |   .  |
    4    |     ABC    |   .  |  joe  , nash  , brad
    5    |     XYZ    |   .  |  jeff , michael ,gerard, pique
    6    |     JKQ    |   .  |  archeo , michael ,neymar, schultz
```

---

Another **table (name = followed)** containing rows:

```
   id    |  names
    1    |  jeff
    2    |  michael
    3    |  cheryl
    4    |  zohan
```

---

> *Given* : Two tables
>
> *To fetch* : Titles from **posts** table where **names.posts** contains atleast one name from **names.followed** in **followed** table
>
> *Result I should get in the above example* : XYZ , JKQ
>
> *query form* : mysql , PDO

---

I dont know if its possible .The reason I am storing values in cells with names concatenated with commas is to reduce redundancy. I have basic query knowledge only .*If its possible* it will be great if some one can answer me a query/queries to get asked result . *If not possible* just give me an alternative method with a different table structure and an explanation why its the best alternative solution .

Big Thanks to all who can help me in any way possible

Comment: Read this: **[Is using multiple foreign keys separated by commas wrong, and if so, why?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17808/is-using-multiple-foreign-keys-separated-by-commas-wrong-and-if-so-why)** And also this: **[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)**

Comment: @ypercube then can you pls give me an alternative table structure for the example I posted above ?

Comment: @ypercube if values seperated with commas is wrong then should I make seperate tables for each title ? I want a redundancy free solution

Comment: @zword - imagine 3 tables: `Posts` -> `PostsPeople` -> `People`.  `PostsPeople` contains `PostID` and `PeopleID`.

Comment: Yes CREATE TABLE POST(id int, ..., name varchar(25)); INSERT INTO POST VALUES (1, 'joe'); INSERT INTO POST VALUES(1, 'nash'); INSERT INTO POST VALUES(1, 'brad'); INSERT INTO POST VALUES(2, 'jeff')... &c. Better would be to just put in the id from the NAME table - joining made easier (note singular names for tables). PK on the two ids - or if you want to keep the text name, PK on id and name in POST. It's a joining table - classic db design pattern.

Comment: @Vérace but is creating a table for each title the proper way?

Comment: I'm saying have a RECORD (not a table) for each post - a post is an instantiation of an entity (a post somewhere) - each post should have its own record. What you're doing is a gross breach of Codd's rules (2?) - Datums should be indivisible. See yepercube's first comment. Max Vernon and I are telling you the exact same thing.

Comment: @MaxVernon if you are sure about your comment can you post a detailed answer?

Comment: Similar question: [Many To Many Relationships](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29675/many-to-many-relationships). The answer there - a junction (or intersection) table - is what @MaxVernon suggested. Try it.

Comment: I would post an example, but I don't do MySQL.

Comment: @MaxVernon ok post me the correct table structure I should use using my example values and any query language u prefer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were doing this in SQL Server<sup>*</sup>, I would use:

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE Posts
(
    PostID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    , PostName VARCHAR(255)
    /*  whatever other fields relate to POSTS */
    , CONSTRAINT PK_Posts PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PostID) 
);
CREATE TABLE People
(
    PeopleID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    , PersonName VARCHAR(255)
    /* whatever other fields relate to PEOPLE */
    , CONSTRAINT PK_People PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PeopleID) 
);
CREATE TABLE PostsPeopleXRef
(
    PostID INT NOT NULL 
    , PeopleID INT NOT NULL 
    , CONSTRAINT FK_PostsPeopleXRef_PostID 
        FOREIGN KEY (PostID) REFERENCES Posts(PostID)
    , CONSTRAINT FK_PostsPeopleXRef_PeopleID 
        FOREIGN KEY (PeopleID) REFERENCES People(PeopleID)
);

INSERT INTO Posts (PostName) VALUES ('Post Test 1');
INSERT INTO People (PersonName) VALUES ('Jack');
INSERT INTO People (PersonName) VALUES ('Jill');
INSERT INTO People (PersonName) VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO PostsPeopleXRef (PostID, PeopleID) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO PostsPeopleXRef (PostID, PeopleID) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO PostsPeopleXRef (PostID, PeopleID) VALUES (1, 3);

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Posts;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.People;

SELECT P.PostName, E.PersonName
FROM dbo.PostsPeopleXRef X
    INNER JOIN dbo.Posts P ON X.PostID = P.PostID
    INNER JOIN dbo.People E ON X.PeopleID = E.PeopleID
ORDER BY P.PostName
    , E.PersonName;
```

This results in the following output:

[image]

*
*: for MySQL, you'll need some changes, like replacing `IDENTITY(1,1)` with `AUTO_INCREMENT`, removing the `CLUSTERED` keyword, adding the `ENGINE = InnoDB` at the `CREATE TABLE` statements, etc.*

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question of "is it possible?" The answer is yes although I agree with the others' advice about a 3rd table that links posts to people.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a97df/2)

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.title, a.names 
FROM Posts a 
JOIN Followed b ON a.names LIKE  concat(concat('%', b.names), '%');
```

Comment: Possible, sure.  Advisable, certainly not.  Scalable, certainly not.

Comment: I totally agree with you Max.

Comment: Prone to error, yes. Will identify `jeff` as `jeffrey`, `brad` as `bradley`, `mary` as `mary-jane`, `nick` as `nicky`, ...

Comment: It does give the answer for what I asked but doing this is not good as others said and I want the best possible method.So I will give you a +1 for aswering for what I asked

Comment: Yes, I definitely wouldn't go this route. This was more for informational purposes if you were unable to change table structures and forced to do it this way.

Comment: @ypercube Good catch. Reminds me to be careful with wildcards.

Comment: @Jchao: I should have used `Eve` as `Steve` for dramatic effect. You can also use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function if there are no spaces between names but only a comma, much better than LIKE/CONCAT.