# Student and Course Relationship - Grade and Attendance

Tags: many-to-many

I was reading on this [DBA page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29675/many-to-many-relationships), about Student and Course relationship, and the use of a junction table. Suppose I wanted to do two things:

- Include the student grade for each course
- Allow the professor to generate an attendance sheet of students

I have a Student `table` like this:

```
Student (id, first name, last name)

Student_Course (student_id, course_id)

Subject (id, name, professorID)
```

Can I place the grade in the `Student_Course` table? What table can I use to generate an attendance sheet with `StudentID`, and `First/Last name`? I'm guessing attendance would be a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the student's grade is logically tied to both the student and the course, `Student_Course` is the best place to put it.

For attendance, you would indeed use a query. You can't generate the attendance sheet from one table. You're starting from a professor and/or course name, and need to get data out of the `Student` table. I suppose you'd need to have some way to connect the professor to the students. In the query, you'd need to find a way to tie each of the tables together. I'd check the documentation for your database, and see if it mentions any way to join tables together in a query.